# Kelly bet question

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, finance

I stumbled upon [Kelly bet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kelly_criterion) during studies and decided to try simulating it. I chose a simple example where $b = 1$ and $p = 0.6$, which gave me the Kelly bet equal to $0.2$ of the wealth. I took $25$ dollars as a starting wealth and did $10000$ simulations of a $300$ bet game with $11$ possible bets including the Kelly bet, starting from $0$ (yeah, I did get $25$ average in the end, just wanted to make sure my program worked) with increment $0.1$ up to $1.0$ of starting wealth (i.e. full $25$ bet from the get go)

The resulting wealth turned out to be abit unintuitive to me: here is the list of wealths for each bet, i.e $25.0$ is for the bet = $0$ of starting wealth, $9789.283$ is for bet = $0.1$ of starting wealth.

[$25.0, 9789.283, 4322833.16, 68980116.885, 1665088721.462, 92284022.736, 19489.665, 0.012, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0$]

Kelly bet corresponds to $4322833.16$, whichis not the max value for the given bets. It turned out that $0.5$ is the best and $0.2$ is not even close.

Why is it like that? Could someone show an intuitive or direct mathematical reason for this or give me some hints.

Thank you very much

edit: added code in python

```
import random

N = 300
x = [0.0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1.0]
b = 1
p = 0.6 
Iter_cnt = 10000

wealthlist = []
win_rate = 0

def gamble(bet_ratio, prob, win_multi, totalbets):
    wealth = 25
    wincnt = 0
    for i in range(totalbets):
        rnd = random.uniform(0, 1) #random real in (0, 1)
        if rnd >= 1 - prob: #if win
            wincnt += 1
            wealth *= 1+win_multi*bet_ratio 
        else: #if lose
            wealth *= (1-bet_ratio)

    return (wealth, wincnt/totalbets) #return of a tuple with 1st argument being equal to resulting wealth and 2nd argument equal to the ratio for this simulation

avg_res_1bet = 0
avg_wr = 0

for i in x: #iterate over the list of betting ratios
    for j in range(Iter_cnt): #iterate as many times as the value of Iter_cnt 
        avg_res_1bet += gamble(i, p, b, N)[0]/Iter_cnt #calculates the average result for each of the betting ratios
        avg_wr += gamble(i, p, b, N)[1]/(Iter_cnt*len(x)) #calculates the average winrate of all simulations

    wealthlist.append(round(avg_res_1bet,3)) #adds the resulting wealth to the final list, rounded to 3 decimals
    avg_res_1bet = 0 #have to nullify in order to make the above command work properly


print("Sample win ratio is: {}".format(avg_wr)) #output
print("Final wealth is: {}".format(wealthlist)) #output
```

Comment: What were the $11$ possible bets?

Comment: $0.0, 0.1, 0.2 ... 0.9$ and $1.0$ of the starting wealth. I.e. $0, 2.5, 5... 22.5$ and $25$

Comment: I think 300 bets is too small. If you up the number of bets (say, 3000), it's much more likely you'll see the correct behavior.

Comment: Your values are far too large.  I have checked saulspatz' result for 178 wins and you wind up with 4668.53 as he says.  There is something wrong with your program

Comment: I'll check it out. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there must be something wrong with your program.  I wrote a python script to try to duplicate your results, and $20\%$ consistently comes out best.  Here's my script:

```
from random import random, seed

seed()
frac = [k/10 for k in range(11)]
bankrolls = 11*[25]
wins = 0
for _ in range(300):
    bets = [f*b for (f,b) in zip(frac, bankrolls)]
    win = random() <= .6
    if win:
        wins += 1
        bankrolls = [r+b for (r,b) in zip(bankrolls, bets)]
    else:
        bankrolls = [r-b for (r,b) in zip(bankrolls, bets)]

print(wins, "wins")
for idx, b in enumerate(bankrolls):
    print(idx, b)
```

Here is sample output:

```
178 wins
0 25.0
1 1525.5418231115136
2 4668.530690514337
3 605.0866915333761
4 2.2038544365635504
5 0.00010387825597102039
6 1.5227053142812533e-11
7 4.2329300312072035e-22
8 3.648424706789544e-39
9 1.0377218907500444e-71
10 0.0
```

**EDIT**

I can't find an error in your code, but both our scripts are rather silly.  If you start with a bankroll of $B,$ win $W$ times and lose $L$ times, then your bankroll at the end is $B(1+r)^W(1-r)^L$ where $r$ is the percentage you bet each hand.  There is no need to do simulations.

You can experiment and see that the ending bankroll is highly sensitive to $W$.  With $r=.2,$ an initial bankroll of 25, and $300$ total bets, $W=170$ gives an ending bankroll of $182.16,$ and $W=190$ gives an ending bankroll of $605724.76.$  (Note that the standard deviation of the number of wins is $\sqrt{72}\approx8.5$ so these are not outlandish outcomes.)

I think the flaw in your program is that you are running different simulations for each betting rate.  Since the number of wins is not the same for the various regimes, the outcome aren't comparable.

It would be more informative to simply make a table comparing the ending bankroll for different betting ratios and numbers of wins.

Thank you for posting this question.  I'd never heard of the Kelly bet before.  I'd be interested to know if there are studies taking the probability of ruin into account.  For example, if the bettor is a bank or an insurance company say, and it has a string of losses, its reserves will fall below the statutory minimum long before it loses all it capital, and the appropriate regulatory authority will shut it down.  How should this be reflected in choosing the optimum bet?  For an individual gambler, it's easy to say, "When you've lost all can afford to, go home," but a financial institution can't do that.

Comment: Thank you for your input. I added my code. Not as pythonic as yours, truly. I can't find the mistake in my code though ...

Answer (score 0):

The notion of taking the average of 10,000 simulations is foreign to Kelly. If you wanted to do it that way, you should have taken the geometric mean, not the arithmetic mean, or equivalently (to avoid numeric overflow) averaged the logs of the wealth, then taken the antilog of the average.

Or you could have just done one simulation of 3,000,000 trials, rather than the geometric mean of 10,000 simulations of 300 trials. The two are identical, Kelly-wise, as long as you express the results in the same units.

Your program did exactly what you wanted it to do. The results are still highly instructive, just not Kelly. They are discussed in comments so as not to clutter this answer.

Comment: By averaging over 10,000 trials, you are calculating the Expected Value of the wealth. EV is the arithmetic mean. Kelly does not maximise EV. (It maximises the geometric mean.)

If you wanted to maximise EV, you would just bet 100% of your bank each time. The EV would then be 
25 * 2^300 * (0.6)^300 = 1.42E+25

This is the value you would have got in the last column if only you had done enough simulations! But that would have taken rather longer.

Comment: In practice, when devising a strategy, it is far more useful to know that in 10,000 trials your return was zero 10,000 times running, than it is to know that your EV was actually 14 trillion trillion dollars all along. That's why you use Kelly.

Comment: OP's results, though wildly different from saulspatz, are indeed exactly what you would expect from averaging 10,000 saulspatz runs. The outliers raise the average.

Comment: saulspatz gave the results of a single simulation of 300 bets with an observed win rate very close to 0.6, so it's no surprise that the results align with Kelly. That is a typical result. OP gave the average of 10,000 simulations of 300 bets, so OP's results are closer to the EV, which is NOT typical(!) As evident from the extreme example above, for large %bet the EV is far higher than any result that you would ever actually observe in less than the age of the universe. To all intents and purposes, the 100% bet EV over 300 trials is meaningless.